# Issue with Completablefuture exception handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, completable-future

I have 2 completableFuture (cf), I need to run them sequentially and "B" should run only if "A" is complete and should not run if A fails for any reason.

My code looks like this :

```
CompletableFuture<String> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> doA(arg)).whenComplete(() -> doB(arg));
```

With the above, doB runs even when doA throws an exception. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look at the [documentation of CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) shows that the [`whenComplete`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) method *always* runs the given `BiConsumer`, even if execution wasn't successful (i.e. if it just finishes executing):

> Returns a new CompletionStage with the same result or exception as this stage, that executes the given action when this stage completes.

The method that you're looking for is [`thenRun`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenRun(java.lang.Runnable)):

> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, executes the given action. See the CompletionStage documentation for rules covering exceptional completion.

Which only runs the given `Runnable` if the previous stage (`doA()` in your case) executes successfully.

Comment: You're ignoring the arguments to the whenComplete action that will tell you whether or not the previous stage succeeded.  If th != null, it failed, and th will tell you why.  You *can* use something like thenRun, but in the case of previous failure, you have little to distinguish "previous stage not finished" and "previous state failed".